# Why am I getting random ! in body of E-Mail when viewed in Outlook

Tags: php, outlook, phpmailer

I am seemingly getting random characters, mainly a rogue `!` in E-Mails read in Outlook.

I am using:

- php 5.3.2
- phpMailer 5.2.0
- very basic html

I have no linked css, everything is inline and fairly simple.

So I have:

```
To approve these expenses you can either:<br>
```

and in Outlook (Outlook 2011 on OS X, Outlook 2011 Windows 7 and OWA) I get:

```
To approve these expenses you can eithe! r:
```

This has happened randomly but it has always been in the middle of characters, it has never replaced any html tags.

When I look at the html generated in OWA it looks the same.

Am I missing something or do I need to be doing something specific for outlook when sending html E-Mail?

[Here's the source from Outlook, E-Mail addresses have been changed.](http://reljac.com/so_1/outlook.txt)  The line from the above example is 173 in the linked file.

RESOLUTION:
So, taking Mathieu's answer I went ahead and randomly inserted `"\n"` after lines of text and after each of my rows.  The output did not change any and the rogue `!` went away.

Comment: Can you post the source of the message, headers and all?

Comment: I added a link to the full text of the message above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an interesting link related to your problem: http://drupal.org/node/31524

Here's the interesting part:

> The email messages can't have more than 998 characters on one line. Tinymce is removing all line breaks from the html code and there for all characters are in the same line.

If you insert a few line breaks in your HTML body I believe this will fix your problem.